# How to find short names of git branches with a specific string?

Tags: git, bash, github

I am building a bash script for git where I want to display the short names for feature branches only. The project has three long term branches: dev, QA, and master. Feature branches are prefixed by 'feature/'

To get the list of only feature branches I am doing:

`git branch --all --list *feature*`

This returns a list like:

```
remotes/origin/feature/good-feature
remotes/origin/feature/new-feature
remotes/origin/feature/best-feature
```

I would like to get just the short names, rather than the prefix 'remotes/origin/feature/'. So the code would return:

```
good-feature
new-feature
best-feature
```

Is there some option like --short I can add which will return only the feature name?

Comment: Can you use some shell utils to achieve this? or looking for a solution with `git` utils?

Comment: I'd prefer if there was a git command to do it. I know there is command: git symbolic-ref --short HEAD which only prints the short branch names. Was looking for some similar option with the git branch command.

Comment: you don't want to script git branch, you want git for-each-ref and then use something like %(refname:lstrip=-1) as a --format